# Rendering error occures at 60th frame

Tags: rendering

after rendering animation 60 frames error blurring tiles occurred i started at 80th frame but still same problem. the blurring starts with small boxes when the tiles tries to render at 60th frame and covers everything.

Comment: Rendering what? Have you enabled Motion Blur? Can you recreate the issue on a new Blender file. Can you upload a file showing the issue. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: rendering animation using cycles render. motion blur is off.

Comment: would need to see at least the output showing the issue (along with what it should render as) but ideally upload to giantcowfilms.You can always cut out anything irrelevant to the issue.